# display custom module created for magento in Ultimate module Creator

Tags: magento

I have created a module in Ultimate Module creator . Its working well in backend but its not shown in front end.Means its is not shown in the products.Any one help me.
thanks

Comment: Please provide more info. Are you trying to add product attributes that doesnt show on the product list page?

Comment: yes sir. i have created this module to add more attributes like color and weight. how can i will show it while buying a product.thanks

Comment: Hello i found another module creator check this link http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to display it on the product detail page.

You can manually do

> echo $_product->getData('attribute_name');

or

> echo $_product->getAttributeName();

If you want the attributes to automatically display in **'Additional Information'** (see image below)

[image]

Then in your **install script** you need to

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_name', array(
        ...
        'visible_on_front'  => true,
        ...
    ));
```

or

Select the attribute you want to display in

> Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Then update 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end' to "YES"